Pycharm unable to recognize clr.AddReference()
Issue:

I need to use the AddReference() function from the clr module that is included in the pythonnet library. The clr module is located in a file called clr.pyd
Upon importing the clr module, pycharm successfully imports clr.pyd. I have verified this my printing inspect.getmodule(clr) and checking that 'AddReference' is listed as an attribute. I also printed the directory that clr is coming from and confirmed that it is pulling from the clr.pyd file.
Upon using the clr.AddReference() function, or any function that is included in the clr module, pycharm tries to look for the function under a file called clr.py (instead of clr.pyd). I have verified to the best of my ability that there is no file called clr.py on my laptop.
I have no idea why the function is imported correctly, but pycharm does not reference it correctly.

Background:

I need to use the clr.AddReference() function that is included in the pythonnet library.
I am required to use pythonnet 2.5.2 and I have it installed properly.
I am using pycharm and believe this is a pycharm IDE issue
I am required to use Python 3.8.10
This has nothing to do with the fact I am using a scratch file

Screenshot of errors
I have already tried uninstalling everything python related from my laptop (using Perfect Uninstaller software) and reinstalling python and pythonnet. This has not fixed the issue. I've been struggling with this issue for weeks now, anything helps. Thanks!
Edit: I have also tried this in visual studio and the same thing happened.
Edit: So pycharm is interpreting clr.pyd and creating a clr.py file on its own. So no matter what I do, Pycharm will try to pull functions from clr.py. If I go to the definition AddReference() in clr.py, the function definition is always empty.
